# How NEON handle overflow?

Tags: arm, overflow, neon

I wonder how Neon handle overflow. E.g:

```
uint8x8_t vadd_u8 (uint8x8_t, uint8x8_t)
```

as I understood, this is a addition of 2 vector (each has 8-elements of unsigned byte). Suppose all values of both vectors are 255.

What result should we expect in this case? A 8-elements vector (510,...510) or something else?

Answer (score 5):

8-bit element can have values only from 0 to 255. It can not contain 510.

vadd_u8 will wrap around => 255 + 255 = 510 % 256 = 254.

vqadd_u8 will saturate => 255 + 255 = min(510, 255) = 255.

Comment: So how can we add 2 uint8x8 vector using Neon intrinsics? AFAIK, there is no method that allow addition of 2 uint8x8 vectors which give uint16x8 result. Refs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html

Comment: `vaddl_u8` will add two `uint8x8` and return a `uint16x8`.